# If I need to sort objects by a sum of 2 fields, what is the most efficient way to do this [Django]

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a class called `LogSheet` that looks like this:

```
class LogSheet(models.Model):
    calls_logged = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    texts_logged = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

What would be the best way to get a queryset that is sorted by the `calls_logged` + `texts_logged`. Is there a way to index this query?

Comment: you  can do it with `LogSheet.objects().all().order_by('calls_logged','texts_logged')`

Comment: You can also define inside the models in `Meta` class like `class Meta: ordering=['calls_logged,'texts_logged']`

Answer (score 1):

you can do using following code,

```
LogSheet.objects.annotate(sum_logged=F("calls_logged")+ F("texts_logged")).order_by("sum_logged").all()
```

Comment: Any idea how I could index this?

Comment: please tell me the requirement bit clear.